# ansible-playbook command line pass ip address for a host group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, autoscaling

I am setting up an Ansible dynamic inventory configuration for my project. When an AWS autoscaling event occurs, a request goes out to Jenkins (which is managing build process through Ansible) to trigger the build on the newly added server.

As the dynamic inventory is using a tag based approach, an autoscaling event adds a new server and a build is triggered. However a fresh build is triggered on all servers as the same tag is present in both old and newly added server.

The approach I am taking to solve it is to be to pass public ip parameter to Jenkins in parameterised build process. This public IP can then be made available to decide either of two Ansible commands:

```
if ["x$public_ip" == "x"] then
    ansible-playbook -i inventories/demo api.yml
else
    ansible-playbook -i $public_ip, api.yml
```

The first command will essentially instruct Ansible to run build process on all servers bearing the tag.

From the second command I wish to tell ansible that it should run the build only on the newly added server. My api.yml file looks like

```
---
- hosts: apiservers
  sudo: yes
  roles:
    - common
```

Now I should be able to tell what the host 'apiservers' mean, or essentially what all IPs are contained in this group. If there are more hosts involved, I should be able to pass multiple groups and their corresponding IP addresses in the same command run through the shell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your playbooks should be completely idempotent so that running against the whole group of hosts each time you spin up a new instance is not only non destructive but desirable as it prevents drift of the configuration of these instances (from people manually changing things on the box).

However, if you can't easily make your Ansible roles idempotent and do just want to target the new instances as they are created then Ansible already exposes this ability to limit the instances you target using the [`--limit` argument](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html).

So you might instead be better off changing your script to something like this instead:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/demo --limit=${public_ip} api.yml
```

If `${public_ip}` is set then it will limit it to just that single IP address and thus that instance alone. If it is not set then a blank `--limit` is equivalent to running the entire inventory.